# Background url in external css not loading on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, url, background, external

Please I have been having a problem with background image url referenced in my external css. I have gone through all the answers to similar questions asked but none is working. I am trying to put a background imagine to an archor tag with a class name tw. It is not the problem of the path because i tried it in my html in img tag and it worked perfectly...If i put the same path in the url in my css file, the browser shows me an error of file not found. i don't know what the problem is.
Here is the code,

````
```
a.tw{ 
      background: url(images\tw.png)
  no-repeat center;
   }

```
````

Comment: is that path existing relative to the html you tried, where it worked or relative to the css file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would specify the exact attribute, which is `background-image` (see https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) and use quotes as well:

```
a.tw{ 
      background-image: url("images/tw.png");
}
```

If you want to use custom `background`, then you can try:

```
a.tw{ 
      background: url("images/tw.png") no-repeat center;
}
```

Comment: I have tried that too, but it is still not loading on the browser.

Comment: @Osahe how is the URL of your page looking alike?

Comment: I have found the problem...i used a back slash instead of a forward slash in my url. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Osahe I'm glad you have passed this problem successfully!